# Setting up the Slim framework

Tags: php, slim

I'm following the tutorial on: http://www.slimframework.com/docs/tutorial/first-app.html

And it's telling me to add the following code to my index.php file:

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $name = $request->getAttribute('name');
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");

    return $response;
});
$app->run();
```

However when I use Postman to do an API call to my server running the php program above I get the following response:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you've missed the step about configuring your .htaccess file.

Comment: I had misspelled the name of the .htaccess file. I've corrected it now. However I'm getting an empty response body from my server now.

Comment: where have you installed your slim, i mean in which directory???

Comment: Slim was installed 1 folder directory too high. Problem solved; thanks guys!